# How to get post request using node and ionic

Tags: angularjs, node.js, post, ionic-framework

My `index.html` file in ionic looks as follows...

```
<ion-content>
  <form name="login" method="post" action="/">
    <div class="list list-inset">
    <label class="item item-input">
      <input type="text" placeholder="First Name">
    </label>
    <label class="item item-input">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name">
    </label>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </div>
</form>
</ion-content>
```

Its a simple form, that's all. But when submit is clicked I want to be able to catch the request using node.js.

I have a separate server file with the following in it...

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.post('/', function (req, res) {
    console.log("post worked");
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
});
```

In Ionic, in my angular `app.js` I am trying to connect to this node.js server file...

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {

      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
});

.factory('Session', function ($resource) {
  return $resource('http://XXX.XXX.X.XX:3000/sessions/:sessionId');
});
```

But I do not think the connect is working. I'm using my private IP to connect. How can I get this to work? Also, how do I know if node.js is picking up the request? Where will `console.log("post worked")` print to?

EDIT

I changed my angular module to Mini Bhati's answer...

```
angular.module('starter',['ionic','ngResource']);
```

but I still cannot get the POST request

Comment: Where is your `/` router where you want to listening in server side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the dependency injection on the `ngResource` module for using **$resource** in your main app module (app.js in your case) as Angular does not come bundled with the $resource service.

```
angular.module('starter',['ionic','ngResource']);
```

Also, please make sure the script angular-resource.js is included in your HTML page.

Comment: This solved the `ngResource` error, but I still can't get the `post` to work. Any idea why?

Comment: The sessionId needs to be passed in the **$resource** service as well. Like this `$resource('http://XXX.XXX.X.XX:3000/sessions/:sessionId',{ sessionId: @_sessionId' });`